# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pypdf (from versions: none)

Tags: installation, pip

I'm having trouble installing pypdf, here is my error message after executing:  **pip install pypdf**

```
   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f012437ffa0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pypdf/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f01243a0310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pypdf/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f01243a0670>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pypdf/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f01243a0820>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pypdf/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f01243a09d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pypdf/
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pypdf (from versions: none)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for pypdf
    WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

To be honest, I don't quite understand the error messages. From what I could see on the net the problem comes surely from opencv? I already try upgrating pip and the following command:

```
pip install opencv-python
pip install python-opencv
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

But everytimes I got the same problem with "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Temporary failure in name resolution

Your internet connection was bad. Try again later.
It might also be issues with your DNS configuration.

You can try `ping pypi.org`. The result should look like this:

```
64 bytes from 2a04:4e42:200::223 (2a04:4e42:200::223): icmp_seq=3 ttl=60 time=5.67 ms
64 bytes from 2a04:4e42:200::223 (2a04:4e42:200::223): icmp_seq=4 ttl=60 time=8.74 ms
64 bytes from 2a04:4e42:200::223 (2a04:4e42:200::223): icmp_seq=5 ttl=60 time=16.2 ms
64 bytes from 2a04:4e42:200::223 (2a04:4e42:200::223): icmp_seq=6 ttl=60 time=9.06 ms
64 bytes from 2a04:4e42:200::223 (2a04:4e42:200::223): icmp_seq=7 ttl=60 time=7.50 ms
64 bytes from 2a04:4e42:200::223 (2a04:4e42:200::223): icmp_seq=8 ttl=60 time=6.09 ms
64 bytes from 2a04:4e42:200::223 (2a04:4e42:200::223): icmp_seq=9 ttl=60 time=9.54 ms
```

If there is nothing happening, it's definitely your internet connection / DNS configuration. It's not related to any of the packages.

You can also check https://status.python.org/ - maybe PyPI has/had issues. But that is very rare.